# MySQL Use Distinct or Group By in XREF Table Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I'm building a php configurator with a series of relationships which I'm controlling with MySQL XREF tables.

There is one XREF table which has multiple dependencies as below:

Table: **cto_body_deck_rear_chassis_xref**

| body_id | deck_type_id | rear_id | chassis_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 20 | 23 | 13 |
| 23 | 20 | 18 | 17 |
| 23 | 20 | 21 | 17 |
| 23 | 20 | 24 | 17 |
| 24 | 20 | 18 | 17 |
| 25 | 21 | 22 | 14 |

Each complete combination is unique although there are similarities between columns; however, I'm getting a duplication problem when selecting from a deck type table, relative to a body id variable passed in the URL.

Table: **cto_deck_type**

| deck_type_id | deck_type_content |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Single Deck |
| 21 | 3/4 Length Fixed 2nd Deck |
| 22 | Full Length Fixed 2nd Deck |

If I use the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT d.deck_type_id, d.deck_type_content
FROM cto_deck_type d
LEFT JOIN cto_body_deck_rear_chassis_xref xref
ON xref.deck_type_id = d.deck_type_id
WHERE xref.body_id = 23
```

I get 3 results, even though each result is identical because the body_id and deck_type_id match 3 times (20).

If the results are identical, I want to group them together or select distinct but I'm not sure what the statement should look like?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT d.deck_type_id, d.deck_type_content
FROM cto_deck_type d
LEFT JOIN cto_body_deck_rear_chassis_xref xref
ON xref.deck_type_id = d.deck_type_id
WHERE xref.body_id = 23
;; and add the line
GROUP BY d.deck_type_id, d.deck_type_content

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  I wasn't sure it could be that straight forward!